# I need to log a certain snippet of information in a batch file, and I don't know how

Tags: windows, batch-file, logging, dos

Okay so I am currently creating a Artificial Intelligence program (VERY basic),
and I need to be able to log the name inputted by the user. I don't understand from other articals posted. 
Here's the area of code:

```
set /p input= Before we talk, I'd like to ask your name so I can properly address you. Please print your name.
set /p Name=
```

As you can see here, we have  an input area and I need the file to save the inputted text, and re-open the file and use the name, every time you go onto this program.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

call :GetName
if not defined Name (
   echo Before we talk, I'd like to ask your name. Please print your name.
   set /p Name=
   echo set "Name=!Name!" >> "%~F0"
) else (
   echo Hello %Name%, I am glad to see you again.
)

rem The rest of the code goes here...


goto :EOF

rem Be sure that the next is the last line in this file:
:GetName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set /p Input=Enter name?
echo set Input=%input% > "c:\somefolder\somefile.bat"
```

to use

```
if not defined %input% call "c:\somefolder\somefile.bat"
```

See `if /?`, `echo /?`, and `set /?`.